# SQL, BETWEEN and CASE (3 COndition Parameter)

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, reportingservices-2005, between

I am getting stuck on some SQL with a CASE condition.

Its a back end for a SSRS 2005 report and the user can select ALL, < 50k, or > 50K

The guts are..

```
SELECT LOANAMOUNT
FROM LOANS
WHERE loanAmount (CASE WHEN @Parameter 'All' THEN  = loanAmount  --Ignore the variable
ELSE @parameter = 1 THEN <= 50k
ELSE @parameter = 2 THEN > 50K
END CASE)
```

The issue I am having is the >< signs.  I can factor in the = but I can't tell it to get ALL then change my operators in the case.

Any insights would be great.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*All*=Select All Records

or depends upon `@Parameter` values will be filtered

```
SELECT *
FROM LOANS
WHERE
 (@Parameter = 'All') OR
 (@Parameter = '1' AND loanAmount <= 50000) OR
 (@Parameter = '2' AND loanAmount > 50000)
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a `case` at all

```
SELECT LOANAMOUNT
FROM LOANS
WHERE @Parameter 'All'
OR (@parameter = '1' AND loanAmount <= 50000)
OR (@parameter = '2' AND loanAmount > 50000)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this will be fastest

```
SELECT *
FROM LOANS
WHERE
 (@Parameter = 'All') OR
 (@Parameter = '1' AND loanAmount <= 50000) OR
 (@Parameter = '2' AND loanAmount > 50000)
```

Note, @Parameter must be of type string so compare to `'All'`, `'1'` and `'2'`.

loanAmount is a number.  `50K` means nothing as a number constant, use the whole number.

Answer (score 0):

For a solution that actually uses `CASE`:

```
SELECT LOANAMOUNT
FROM LOANS
WHERE CASE WHEN @Parameter = 'All' THEN 1
        WHEN @Parameter = 1 AND loanAmount <= 50000 THEN 1
        WHEN @Parameter = 2 AND loanAmount >  50000 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END = 1
```